# How to skew points on a line towards a given point on that line?

Tags: functions, curves

I'm looking for a function that will skew values towards an arbitrary given value (c) in one-dimensional space.

For example, suppose a student response is scored (s) from 0 to 100.  The threshold to be considered correct is c=80.  I would like to skew the scores towards 80, so that as scores approach 80, there is less difference between them.  Furthermore, scores of 0, 80, and 100 should not change (i.e. the function should intersect the line "y=x" (or rather "s_original = s_skewed") at those points).

I'm picturing some kind of cubic curve that starts at (0,0), arcs slightly above y=x, levels out and passes through (c,c), then curves under the final segment and finally intersects (100,100).

Comment: What would your axis represent? are you trying to represent a probability distribution function?

Comment: The axis are just the score and the transformed score.  I want to transform scores so that the closer they are to the threshold of being correct, the more they are skewed toward that value.  It will help to isolate scores on the extreme ends and bring scores that are closer to the threshold closer together.

Comment: You seem to have a general idea of what you want the function to look like - it will be possible to determine the equation of a cubic give 4 points it passes through

Comment: I only know 3 points I want it to pass through. Here is a physical description of what I want: if you fastened a flexible rod at points (0,0) and (100,100), grabbed it at point around (80,80) and twisted it a bit, that's the line I'm trying to graph.  I'm not sure how much of a twist I want though.

Comment: Try to choose a point such as (75,85) and observe the general shape of the curve. Then you can change the values of the last point to get the shape you want

Comment: Or if you know the "turning points" of the graph (when it goes from increasing to decreasing) it is also possible to determine the equation

Comment: The blue line in this graph is what I'm looking to graph.  See how it's very close to the straight (red) line, but it's twisted a bit around point (80,80).  The purpose is so that, as you can see on the vertical axis, the scores are skewed towards the threshold value of 80,  while values of 0, 80, and 100 remain the same.  See: http://i.imgur.com/K6hzCnS.png

Comment: Ideally, the shape of the curve would be determined by only 2 values... the threshold point (between 0 and 100; 80 in my example), and the amount of "twist" I want to occur at point 80, where a twist of 0 would produce a straight line, and a twist of 45 degrees would produce something more like a standard y=x^3, where it flattens out around the center of the curve (at point 80,80 in this case).

Comment: A 4-point beizer curve would work, but I'd need a formula to govern where the two central control points should be, given a threshold value like x=80. I know both of their x-coordinates should be equal to the threshold of 80, and then I could determine the y value of one, given a y value of the other. The amount by which the y coordinate of the control point that falls below the x=y line would determine the degree of twist, and then the y coordinate of the other control point would have to be moved far enough above the line such that the curve intersects (x=y) at that threshold value of x=80.

Comment: I figured it out.  Here, try sliding the slider for variable C.  notice that the black line always intersects x=y at c.  Also, if you adjust 'f', that's the degree of twist.  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ylol4pbcfs

Answer (score 0):

Adjust variable c's slider to adjust the threshold.
Adjust variable f's slider to adjust the degree of distortion.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ylol4pbcfs

I noticed something was slightly off with the intersection, but after some careful adjustment, I discovered that the 2/3 exponent should really be closer to 1/1.080435 (through trial and error getting it to intersect better).  When I looked up 1.08043... I discovered that value is actually the L. Cot of 45 degrees (see pg. 42 here: [Table 4 degrees pg. 42](http://books.google.com/books?id=ctpHAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=1.08043&source=bl&ots=3u12H2uEam&sig=eG8iRmHg72Zu0HzkCv3f_P5sQqg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=msggU_ScEsGN0AHJroHwCg&ved=0CKsBEOgBMBg#v=onepage&q=1.08043&f=false)), which is the slope of the x=y line.  Since that value results in higher and higher precision, I'm sure it's correct.  Or not, just an oddly precise coincidence?